# Python gives TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions. while scraping data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My code opens chrome but right after few seconds i get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File"C:\Users\SACHIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Flipkart\mobiles.p",
>   line 25, in mobile_script
>       wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3wU53n")))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\SACHIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sitepackages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
>   line 80, in until
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Following is my code snippet:

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
counter = 0
for a in brands:
    URL = "https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/pr?sid=6bo%2Fb5g&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3D" + a

    wd.get(URL)

    wait=WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3wU53n")))
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try by giving just one space after your class name `_3wU53n `.

Comment: I have tried this but still i get the same error.

Comment: There are multiple elements of same class name. What exactly you want to achieve here can you explain in detail.

Comment: product name,price and ratings

Comment: Try the below solution with CSS_SELECTOR